How do I set a state from a prop in React?
I am newish to React and am using React Select (https://react-select.com/) to create a dropdown list. I want to wrap this in my own component, so I can send React Select a specific set of props based off the props I give the wrapping component.
Whilst I have wrapped React Select in my own component fine, I am unable to figure out how to set React Select's states with my wrapping component's props.
Eg I want to set the isDisabled value, and have the following:
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import Select from 'react-select';
import './select.scss';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const MySelect = ({ options, disable }) => {

  const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(disable);

  return (
    <Select 
      options={options} 
      isDisabled={isDisabled}
    />
  );
};

MySelect.propTypes = {
  disable: PropTypes.bool,
  options: PropTypes.array,
};

MySelect.defaultProps = {
  disable: false,
  options: [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
  ]
};

export default MySelect;

Whilst React Select does respect the disable prop when I set the default, eg:
MySelect.defaultProps = {
      disable: true,

It does not respect it when I call the component itself, eg:
<MySelect options={someOptions} disable={true} />

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

You're writing 13th century React code - propTypes for example is a separate package and deprecated in favor of compile time Typescript types. Also if using a functional component you can just assign default props as you would to any function arguments ({ disable = false } etc). Why copy props to state in this case anyway? It's better to control your input components from above via props and MySelect is stateless unless there is some temporary state before committing it to the parent but unlikely in the case of a select

Thanks, you're probably right. I'm using Storybook so just copied their examples

If the props change later, the state will not automatically update to reflect these changes.
If you need to update the state in response to prop changes, use the useEffect hook
useEffect(() => {
    setIsDisabled(disable);
  }, [disable]);


While technically correct, this is an anti-pattern. Don't set state based off of props. If this is not controlled at all from within MySelect, simply pass the prop in directly ie isDisabled={disabled}

@Derek, Thanks for pointing that out. As you mentioned, I guess it only makes sense to use useEffect if we want to derive state in a complex way.
